# JavaScript read JSON from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to write an array to localStorage, then later recall that array.

I've written a few lines of code which I thought should achieve that function, although nothing appears to happen. Any advice on what's wrong would be great!

```
localStorage.setItem('storedPerson', "{first:'Bill', last:'Bob', age:'22'}");

var person = localStorage.getItem('storedPerson');

alert(person["age"]); // expected result: '22'.
```

Comment: Go read about [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON).

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedPerson'))`

Comment: That's not an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to encode using JSON.

```
localStorage.setItem('storedPerson', JSON.stringify({first:'Bill', last:'Bob', age:'22'});
var person = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('storedPerson'));
alert(person.age);
```

Make sure you using `JSON.stringify` when storing, because the string you gave is not valid JSON (strings and property names have to be in double quotes).